# Read an XML Response From POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

I am trying to do something similar to this, but I do not fathom how to actually read the XML response.  Where would the syntax recommended by @NikolaiDante actually go?  Does anyone have a full working example?  I would leave a comment there but rep not high enough...

Here is a link to the original post:
[Read XML Response From Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863330/read-xml-response-from-page)

I always use Hanselman example as I understand it, and it is easy to follow

```
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters) 
{
   System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
   req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
   req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   req.Method = "POST";
   byte [] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
   req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
   System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream ();
   os.Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
   os.Close ();
   System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
   if (resp== null) return null;
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

And here is a link to the site so you can see and credit is given:
[enter link description here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx)

Comment: what about the answer that you linked don't you understand? have you tried using `XmlDocument.LoadXml`? also, post the code that will be attempting to parse the XML response. show that you have attempted some of it.

Comment: please post code that you have already tried even if it is just your POST and response.

Comment: @terbubbs - see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take that string you are returning and do this...

```
string result = HttpPost(url, parameters);
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(result);
```

or in your HttpPost method..

```
var stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(stream);
```

You can reference [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse the actual XML document

Comment: Where in my current syntax would I place this?

Comment: I am telling you exactly where to execute this code. To be clear, in the first example, I am calling your POST method and using that return value (`string`) to load the xml.. Notice in the second example, I am using your variable names.. please use that as reference.